# SubscriberAdminClient.pull vs. Subscriber for Google Cloud PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

The Google Cloud PubSub [guide on pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) uses `Subscriber` to consume messages from a subscription. However, `SubscriptionAdminClient` also has a [`pull` method](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_SubscriptionAdminClient_pull_com_google_pubsub_v1_SubscriptionName_int_). The latter is not explored in the guides.

They both work, but is one (likely the former) recommended over the other?

Comment: Your question will be best addressed by the main developers, you may raise an issue tracker following this [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull method in `SubscriptionAdminClient` is really only exposed because it is part of the auto-generated library. Whenever possible, it is best to use the `Subscriber` library, which is a hand-written library designed to optimize for high throughput and low latency. The `pull` method [is covered in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull), though accessed in a slight different way.